# Select MAX of each corresponding row

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

new to SQL but I'll try to be clear,

I have 3 table, which have corresponding key columns. I need to select the row the MAX Value of a set column, for EACH of it's corresponding column.

```
Table1
 ID1  Value1
  1    Marie
  2    Max
  3    John

Table2
 ID2  Value2
  1    First
  2    Second
  3    Third

Table3
 ID1 ID2
  1   1
  1   2
  2   1
  2   2
  2   3
  3   1
```

So far I have something like so;

```
SELECT T1.Value1, T2.Value2 FROM Table1 T1
 INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T1.ID1 = T3.ID1
 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T3.ID2 = T2.ID1
 WHERE (That's where I can't formulate correctly)
```

So far my tables are correctly joined, but I want to output only the rows where ID2 is at it's max value for the corresponding ID1.

So we'd have

```
ID1 ID2
 1   2
 2   3
 3   3
```

And so, from correspondence of value we'd finally have.

```
Value1 Value2
 Marie  Second
 Max    Third
 John   First
```

Any help? Also, group by is prohibited.

Comment: "group by is prohibited" why?

Comment: Read up on `correlated subquery` to solve these types of problems without `group by`

Comment: @HoneyBadger Academic exercise, probably to get a better grasp of relational algebra within SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use MAX in WHERE condition:

```
SELECT
    T1.Value1,
    T2.Value2 
FROM
    Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T1.ID1 = T3.ID1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T3.ID2 = T2.ID1 
WHERE
    T3.ID2 = (
        SELECT
            MAX(T3_alias.ID2) 
        FROM
            Table3 AS T3_alias 
        WHERE
            T3_alias.ID1 = T1.ID1
    )
```